# Can I change the default radio station?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v, grand-theft-auto-online

Question says it all..[as I am starting to get sick of a few channels]  Can I change the default radio station for when I enter any vehicle ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have looked for this for a while too and sadly the answer is no. Currently the stations are picked by the type of drivers driving the car and do not change when you steal them. I'm hoping for a update/patch/mod/hack so you can just listen to your favorite or custom tracks by default.

Comment: Turn music volume down to 0, listen to your own music.

Comment: @kotekzot True but not as immersive then in game radio or custom radio.

Comment: interesting fact: if you're playing offline as Trevor, he will get mad & switch to another radio if he doesn't like the current radio channel.

Answer (score 0):

Go to settings and then select audio and adjust the radio station.

Comment: Does this change the *default* radio station though, or just the one that is currently playing?

Comment: Can you please be more specific @user66164 about what radio station is being changed exactly?